# osm2pgsql: modifing the default.style - newly added columns are empty

Tags: openstreetmap, style, osm2pgsql

I would like to import a osm-db (from planet) with the "name_de" and "source" column. So I added/changed those lines in the default.style:

```
node,way   source       text         linear    
node,way   name_de      text         linear
```

After import, both columns are created but empty. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German names are stored with the "name:de" tag. I would not expect you to find anything in a "name_de" column.

I've created an [issue on github](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/130) about dropping names early in the processing chain.

Comment: http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/name_de collects at least 12 objects with `name_de`.

Comment: Yes, it also shows 254 thousand objects with name:de. It's hard to say without knowing exactly what they're doing, but if they're after German names, name:de is what they want.

Answer (score 1):

The source tag is always deleted. This is hardcoded in 
osm2pgsql / parse-primitive.c and parse-xml2.c:

```
/* 'created_by' and 'source' are common and not interesting to mapnik renderer */
    if (strcmp((char *)xk, "created_by") && strcmp((char *)xk, "source")) {
    ...
```

To keep the source tag, there are two options:

- Change the code and compile osm2pgsql;
- Use a hex editor to change the osm2pgsql binary. Open the binary and search for "created_by". Replace the string "source" that occurs next to it by something else, for example "xxxxxx". Continue searching and replacing, because there are multiple occurrences.